# text sliding "marquee" that doesnt wait for the text to finish then start the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a text slide like marquee but i dont  it to show the text again after it finishes the loop, I want it two show the next one right after the first text finished.

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gR7L2/1/

so I want to make the space between the "hello world" strings to be the same, not to finish the first string then start the other, I dont know if you can understand what I am trying to say.

Here is the html:

HTML

```
<h1>Hello World!<span style="color:#FFF">...................................</span>Hello World!</h1>
```

I think this is a primitive way to do this I know. I didnt know how to display 2 strings for each loop!

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to reinvent this wheel? If I'm not mistaken, this is called a 'javascript news ticker' and there are dozens of them.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen I just found one of them, I think it will do the trick. thank you ;)

Comment: There's the oldskool `<marquee>Hello, world!</marquee>`. And also [some cool CSS3 properties](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3tutorials/a/marquee-in-css.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check this plugin , seems that it's completing your requirements:

http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html